# How to pass a value inside an observeEvent to another one?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to pass a value assigned in an `observeEvent` to another `observeEvent` in shiny. In addition to the codes below, I also attempted to use **my_dynamic_table()**, but unfortunately I couldn't achieve my goal.

My aim is to have "Something 1" on the screen if  **my_dynamic_table** is not empty.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

my_dynamic_table = data.frame(NA)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("call","Call"),
    actionButton("save","Save"),
    verbatimTextOutput('text'), 
    DT::dataTableOutput('table_out')
  
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
   

  observeEvent (input$call ,{
    
    my_dynamic_table <- mtcars
    
    output$table_out <- DT::renderDataTable(

                    my_dynamic_table            

                    ) # renderDataTable : table_out     

    })
    



   observeEvent (input$save,{
        
        output$text <- renderText({ 
                if(nrow(my_dynamic_table)>1) {

                        "Something 1"
                }else {
                        "Something 2"

                }

         }) #renderText

    }) #observeEvent


  } #server
) #shinyApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve that would be to use a `reactiveVal` or  `reactiveValues`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("call", "Call"),
    actionButton("save", "Save"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table_out")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    my_dynamic_table <- reactiveVal(data.frame())
    
    observeEvent(input$call, {
      my_dynamic_table(mtcars)
      
      output$table_out <- DT::renderDataTable(
        my_dynamic_table()
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$save, {
      output$text <- renderText({
        if (nrow(my_dynamic_table()) > 0) {
          "Something 1"
        } else {
          "Something 2"
        }
      }) # renderText
    }) # observeEvent
  } # server
) # shinyApp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I do think that using `reactiveValues` is a good solution to this problem, I'd say its never a good idea to use an `output` inside an `observeEvent()`. I would rearrange the code as below. In the `observeEvent` we observe the action buttons, and when clicked, update the `reactiveValues`. Those are again intermediates for your `output`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("call","Call"),
    actionButton("save","Save"),
    verbatimTextOutput('text'), 
    DT::dataTableOutput('table_out')
    
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    my <- reactiveValues(dynamic_table = data.frame(NA),
                         text = NA)
    
    observeEvent(input$call, {
      
      my$dynamic_table <- mtcars
      
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$save, {
      
      if (nrow(my$dynamic_table) > 1) {
        my$text <- "Something 1"
      } else {
        my$text <-"Something 2"
      }
    }) 
    
    
    output$text <- renderText({
      req(input$save)
      my$text
      })
    
    output$table_out <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(input$call)
      my$dynamic_table            
      
    }) 
    
  } #server
) #shinyApp
```

Comment: could you please explain in short why it is "never a good idea to use an output inside an observeEvent()". Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae: I think first and foremost the main argument against using outputs in `observeEvent`s is code clarity. Shiny makes it easy to reason about code if you think in terms of input => intermediate => output. But what is an output nested in `observeEvent`? It doesn't even exit until the `observeEvent` is run. On SO we see a lot of problematic code, partially caused by nested output statements. Doesn't mean they don't work, but they are more error prone. That is at least my take.